# Grub2 failing to update

Tags: grub2

I recently replaced a disk containing my `/home` partition only. Upon attempting to upgrade my kernal package (Debian Squeeze) I get the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: Couldn't find PV pv1. Check your device.map.
```

Google searching suggested this solution:

```
root@debian1:~# mv /boot/grub/device.map /boot/grub/device.map_orig
root@debian1:~# grub-mkdevicemap
root@debian1:~# update-grub
```

The first two commands succeed without error, yet the third command `update-grub` fails with the same error mentioned above.

I've checked my `/boot/grub/device.map` file, and it seems to match the ids listed when I run `ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/`.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: What does `pvdisplay` show?  My guess is that you were using LVM on the old drive and yanked it out without telling LVM to remove it, so now it's still looking for that disk.

Answer (score 1):

@psusi: You're an extremely good guesser. As you mentioned, I didn't update the LVM file when replacing the disk.

`vgreduce volume_group_name --removemissing` fixed the issue.